# Web audio api audio file abstraction only recognizes the scheduled time on initial playback. It then plays back immediately

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

The goal of the below code is to insure that every time the event listener is fired the sound is played 2 seconds into the future. As it stands this only works the first time the event is fired. All subsequent mousedown events play the file immediately. I am looking for a hint as to how to remedy this.

```
var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext;

function AudioObj(fileDirectory) {
    var soundObj = {};
    soundObj.fileDirectory = fileDirectory;

    var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getSound.open("GET", soundObj.fileDirectory, true);
    getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    getSound.onload = function() {
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer) {
            soundObj.soundToPlay = buffer;

        });
    }

    getSound.send();


soundObj.play = function(time) {
        var playSound = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        playSound.buffer = soundObj.soundToPlay;
        playSound.connect(audioContext.destination);
        playSound.start(time );

      }

      return soundObj;

}


var snare = AudioObj("snare.mp3");

window.addEventListener("mousedown", go);

function go(){
    snare.play(2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The start time is not an offset.  You need to call play sound.start(AudioContext.currentTime + time); in your play() method.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask what the logic behind the implementation of having it play with the scheduled time value the first time? I mean shouldn't I always have to write audioContext.currentTime + (scheduled sound event) ? What's the reasoning behind it working the first time without the full line of code?

Comment: @TaoistWA as you are using webkit, there is still a bug that the context.currentTime starts counting whenever you create your first node. So, as when you the click the node is created, the time starts and then the offset from currentTime is indeed ~2s.

Comment: The problem you eluded to is absolutely true and a webkit issue but regarding my question to Chris - I just tested in Firefox Aurora and it does the same thing.  So I don't think the webkit bug is related.

Comment: the audio context time starts at zero when the audio context is first created - if you immediately create your nodes and start the first one with start(2), it will start two seconds in the future.

Comment: (As MarijnS95 noted, Webkit/Blink still have a bug where time doesn't start ticking until your first node is created.)